# "Error in read_xml.raw" when running code to download a picture from website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am trynig to download a picture from a website (url) base on a specific person's name (in R).
And I get the following error

```
Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
CHAR() can only be applied to a 'CHARSXP', not a 'NULL'
```

This is the trace back

```
19.read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html, 
options = options) 
18.read_xml.connection(con, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = as_html, 
base_url = x, options = options) 
17.read_xml.character(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, 
options = options) 
16.read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options) 
15.withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) if (inherits(w, 
classes)) tryInvokeRestart("muffleWarning")) 
14.suppressWarnings(read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, 
options = options)) 
13.read_html.default(., image_page) 
12.read_html(., image_page) 
11.html_nodes(., "img") 
10.xml2::xml_attr(x, name, default = default) 
9.html_attr(., "src") 
8.handle_url(handle, url, ...) 
7.httr::GET(.) 
6.is.response(x) 
5.stopifnot(is.response(x)) 
4.httr::content(., "raw") 
3.writeBin(., paste0("~/", ceo_name, ".jpg")) 
2.paste0(site, image_page) %>% read_html(image_page) %>% html_nodes("img") %>% 
html_attr("src") %>% {
grep("gstatic", ., value = TRUE)
} %>% 1[] %>% httr::GET() %>% httr::content("raw") %>% writeBin(paste0("~/",  ... 
1.get_image(as.character("Mark Lloyd"))
```

I don't understand why. Please, can someone enlight me?
Thank you very much

**code**

```
> library(rvest)
> library(httr)
> 
> get_image <- function(ceo_name)
+ {
+   site <- "https://www.icobench.com"
+   query <- paste0(site, "/ico/max-crowdfund/team", url_escape(ceo_name))
+   
+   image_page <- read_html(query)                          %>% 
+     html_nodes(xpath = "//a[contains(text(), 'Images')]") %>% 
+     html_attr("href")
+   
+   paste0(site, image_page)             %>%
+     read_html(image_page)              %>%
+     html_nodes("img")                  %>% 
+     html_attr("src")                   %>% 
+     {grep("gstatic", ., value = TRUE)} %>% 
+     `[`(1)                             %>%
+     httr::GET()                        %>%
+     httr::content("raw")               %>%
+     writeBin(paste0("~/", ceo_name, ".jpg"))
+ }
> 
> get_image(as.character("Mark Lloyd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure I have ? to indicate query string in url. I would then use a shorter css selector to pick out the appropriate image off the page. You should really check the status to ensure page found.

With the appropriate node located I would use a regex pattern to pull out the url and pass that, with protocol + domain from url_absolute, to httr direct. Regex because the url is within the style attribute for that page.

Ideally, one should also test that a node was matched before trying to extract an attribute value from it.

As you want only a single image you can use html_node for the ceo node and thus gain the efficiency of exiting after a single node match.

---

This is assuming the actual landing url, complete with `?` would have been:

`https://icobench.com/ico/max-crowdfund/team?Mark%20Lloyd`

For that page your xpath statement is invalid.

---

Not tested with other CEOs.

---

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(stringr)

get_image <- function(ceo_name) {
  site <- "https://www.icobench.com"
  query <- paste0(site, "/ico/max-crowdfund/team?", url_escape(ceo_name))

  image_page <- read_html(query) %>% 
  html_node(paste0('[title="', ceo_name, '"] .image_background')) %>%
    html_attr("style") %>%
    stringr::str_extract("/.*\\.jpg") %>%
    url_absolute(site)

  image_page %>%
    httr::GET() %>%
    httr::content("raw") %>%
    writeBin(paste0("~/", ceo_name, ".jpg"))
}

get_image(as.character("Mark Lloyd"))
```